# Google chrome doesn't show icons of fontawesome

Tags: google-chrome, icons, font-awesome, chromium

I am trying to put some font awesome icons on my site. But google chrome doesn't show icons of fontawesome.com
I have tested with other browsers, it works fine.
I have imported the link of fontawsome CDN in the head tag.
I have also put the tag of icons to show.
There's no adblocker and any extension that blocks icons.
I have tested with chromium browser, same problem with that browser.
I haven't used any extension for chromium.

Note: I am on the latest version of the Chrome browser and also imported the latest version of fontawesome.com
Chrome: Version 74.0.3729.169 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Font. version: 5.8.2

P.S.: It's working fine on another laptop of my friend, but not working in my mine. Please figure out the problem.
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/x6nkm8hL/)
Here's the link of jsfiddle for code:

```
 <!-- Font awesome 4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- The code for icon -->
<div class="icon-container">
    <i class="icon far fa-gem"></i>
</div>
```

Please check the screenshots:
[image: developer tools chrome]
[image: html file]

Comment: Welcome  to SO! It is a bit difficult to help you, as one would have to click through screenshots and then possibly try to build a repro etc. You could make it easier by providing a fiddle (see jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com) which exposes that behaviour.

Comment: @MBaas I edited

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same version of Chrome and that fiddle displays as expected (far-gem is shown).  So I don't think it is a FA-issue or a Chrome-issue. Possibly some addins are causing trouble.

Comment: As I mentioned that I downloaded the Chromium browser and checked in that browser. There's the same problem with that browser also. There are no extensions on chromium browser. So, I don't think. It matters.

Comment: I tried the repro in CEF (Chromium Embedded) and it worked there as well. Confirms that something special is going on on your machine - but that is hard to debug...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with icons not appearing on Google chrome on my mobile phone but worked fine on my laptop.
I solved the problem by clearing my browser cache.  Have you tried this?

I don't know why my browser cache prevented icons from loading or if that could also be a problem for any of my site's visitors - if anyone can explain this, or has a way to ensure this issue doesn't affect my site's visitors, that would be really helpful.